# Compressing and Decompressing Integer

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, compression, rsa, python-cryptography

### Situation:-

I am using Python.
I am using RSA and I am using two 64 bit keys. ***I am not an cryptographer*** . 
I can provide you the RSA code if needed but i am not posting it as it doesn't have to do anything with the problem. I have to give the private key to a human to remember well 64bit key cannot be remembered by normal humans as far as know.

### Problem: -

I want a method to compress my 64bit key to at least an integer of 10 digits and a method when those 10 digits are entered they decompress back to 64bit key.

Solution I have tried: -

Converting my 64 digit integer sequence to an string phrase or a string (the worst Idea wasted a lot of time do not try yourself).

Using basic math operations such as 'division', 'subtraction', etc. This proved to be not a good practice as it is easily readable in the code.

## Note

> `I need not to change the private key whenever programs run but whenever client wishes to.`

Comment: You should rather ask this question @ [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or @ [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Why would anyone remember the key? Isn't it better to send him the key securely so that he can store it however he wants?

Comment: You can't -- pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Not even close. You will need at least 20 decimal digits to represent 64 bits. You can't compress data unless there is some redundancy. A 64-bit key should have very close to 64 bits of entropy, i.e. it is not compressible.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk what if I instead of compressing it reduce it some how to 10 digits.

Comment: Then you have no way of getting the original 64 bits back again.

Comment: ok. What can I say now, @PresidentJamesK.Polk do u use telegram I ewant to discuss about some problem I am facing with crptography

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216289/ritvik-polk)

Comment: Quick trick to get the numbers of digits for a number of bits: divide by 10, multiply by 3, and you have a ballpark figure.